# fullcalendar angular5 cannot select half of the component

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

[image: Example #1]
[image: Example #2]

Using fullcalendar through ap-angular2-fullcalendar

I can only select hours between 12AM up until 3PM. It varies, and depended on if the Console is open or not, so I have more or less space in my screen.
The most I can click on is 3PM if I scrolled to the bottom of the screen and Console not open.

When I drag an existing event forward to the hours I want it in - 3PM and up - it doesn't let me as it appears it is not a part of the calendar - although visually it is.

When I drag an existing event backward - so a part of it is on the previous day - it lets me just fine - although it is a part of those 'forbidden hours' or w/e.

It's really weird.
Anyone knows what is it about?

Comment: Please, don't describe the bug with words, provide a way to replicate it instead. Otherwise the question is off-topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Thanks for commenting @estus, I will try to find a way.

Comment: I added an illustrative picture @estus

Comment: Showing your code would be much more useful than pictures. Perhaps you configured something incorrectly. Also check if there are any errors in your browser console while you're trying to do these actions.

Comment: I bet. well, found the solution eventually - in answers. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a similar problem. It is an issue with Fullcalendar and not me.

Temporary solution provided there: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3615#issuecomment-339333385

`.fc-scroller { overflow-x: visible !Important; }`

Added it to my `styles.css` right below the import:

```
@import '~fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css';

.fc-scroller {
  overflow-x: visible !Important;
}
```